# HTTPS warning issue

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, https

I'm trying to help my friend fix an issue with her Windows laptop.

She recently did some virus scan and now each time she attempts to login to Hotmail or Yahoo or other sites with secure connection she gets a warning that there is no certificate and the website she is trying to access is not secure, etc. This happens every time she tries to visit any email account.

This behaviour is the same on Chrome, Safari or IE.

A MacBook using the same wi-fi network doesn't have the same issues, so I think something is wrong with her computer.

I googled the issue and saw a number of people report having similar issue, but I did not come across any comprehensive fix.

Could you advise on how to fix this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar problem and found it was something with the proxy server.  There are too many possible problems to know exactly what's wrong, but check out [Microsoft's guide to Proxy Servers](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Change-proxy-server-settings-in-Internet-Explorer) for a possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

Could the warning be for an **expired/out-of-date** certificate?

I have a netbook with a dead clock-battery, so every time the main battery is completely drained, the time resets to 2001 (or something like that).

Since the certficates became valid at some point in 2012, they aren't considered valid YET by the netbook.

Once I update the system time, without rebooting, the certificates are considered valid again.